# Maven: Obtaining parent project from SVN when running from TeamCity

Tags: svn, teamcity, maven

I have 3 sibling projects that have a common parent that I'm managing with Maven. The projects share same parent which is one level up. The parent POM has no knowledge of any of the children it simply contains boilerplate, repo definitions and common plugins. Everything works fine until I try to put this on TeamCity. Here's how I do it now

1. Create one configuration per branch
2. Trigger independently of each other based on check-ins

And now comes the problem: since I have a parent POM one level above the project it's not getting pulled when the child code is checked out and the build quickly fails. I suppose I can create another build configuration just to pull the parent (which is of type POM) but is there a better way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I went ahead and created parent configuration. The only catch is: I had to create another folder and move parent POM into it otherwise SVN would pull all the nested folder instead of single POM (checkout rules didn't work too well). So now I have 4 projects on the same level and one of these simply hold a parent POM. After I run parent's `mvn install` once everything works since other projects now would pull configuration from the local repo.

Anyone can provide a better way - I'll greatly appreciate it

Comment: TeamCity team just confirmed that's the way to go